# locationManager startUpdatingLocation crashing app

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-location

This is the first time I'm developing an app. So I want the user's coordinate as well as address to be displayed when a user presses the 'View Location' button in the view controller.

I've coded everything and when I press the button in the simulator, it suddenly closes and points me to the  [newlocationManager startUpdatingLocation] code in the IBAction button's method. It says something like "thread:1 breakpoint 1.1". What does it mean and how can I fix it?

This is my interface file:

```
 @interface FirstViewController : UIViewController <CLLocationManagerDelegate>

 @property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *latitudeLabel;
 @property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *longitudeLabel;
 @property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *addressLabel;

 - (IBAction)getCurrentLocation:(id)sender;

 @end
```

and this is my implementation file:

```
#import "FirstViewController.h"

@interface FirstViewController ()

@end

#pragma - UIViewController // Categorizes a group of methods

@implementation FirstViewController{
    //The CCLocationManager is the object that provides the location data and the methods.
    CLLocationManager * newlocationManager;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    newlocationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

#pragma - IBAction // Categorizes a group of methods

- (IBAction)getCurrentLocation:(id)sender {
    newlocationManager.delegate = self;
    newlocationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest;

    [newlocationManager startUpdatingLocation];
}

#pragma - CLLocationManagerDelegate // Categorizes a group of methods

// Informs the delegate that it was unable to get location data. Displays error pop-up alert.
- (void) locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didFailWithError:(NSError *)error{
    // The error why location could not be retreived
    NSLog(@"didFailWithError: %@", error);
    UIAlertView *errorAlert = [[UIAlertView alloc]
                               initWithTitle:@"Error" message:@"Failed to Get Your Location" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [errorAlert show];
}

- (void) locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateLocations:(NSArray *)locations{
    // Last object of the 'locations' array contains the most recent location. newLocation now points to the last object.
    CLLocation *newLocation = [locations lastObject];
    CLLocation *oldLocation;

    // Check the size of the NSArray (locations). If it contains a single object, just set oldLocation to nil.
    // If it contains more than 1 object then store that in oldLocation.

    if (locations.count>1){
        oldLocation = [locations objectAtIndex:(locations.count - 2)];
    }
    else
        oldLocation = nil;

    NSLog(@"didUpdateToLocation %@ from %@", newLocation, oldLocation);

    if (newLocation != nil){
    _longitudeLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.8f", newLocation.coordinate.longitude];
    _latitudeLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.8f", newLocation.coordinate.latitude];
    }
    //MKCoordinateRegion userLocation = MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance(newLocation.coordinate, 1500.0, 1500.0);
    //[regionsMapView setRegion:userLocation animated:YES];
}

@end
```

Comment: What error did you get? it might help if you change weak to strong.

Comment: Remove the breakpoint in the debugger or click the "Continue" button after it stops.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like you're hitting a breakpoint. There might not be anything wrong. Do you see something like this? http://cl.ly/image/0T1G3n300G1r

[image: Xcode Breakpoint indicator]

If so, just click and drag it away from the gutter. It will disappear. The next time you run it wont break there.